# multiple regex substitution in multiple files using python

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I have one project where I need to apply a dozen or so regex to about 100 files using python. 4+ hours of searching the web for various combinations including "(merge|concatenate|stack|join|compile) multiple regex in python" and I haven't found any posts regarding my need.

This is a mid-sized project for me. There are several smaller regex projects that I need which take only 5-6 regex patterns applied over only a dozen or so files. While these will be a great aid in my work, the grand-daddy project is a applying a file of 100+ search, replace strings to any new file I get. (Spelling conventions in certain languages are not standardized and being able to quick-process files will increase productivity.)

Ideally, the regex strings need to be update-able by a non programmer, but that maybe outside of the scope of this post.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import os, re, sys # Is "sys" necessary?

path = "/Users/mypath/testData"
myfiles = os.listdir(path)

for f in myfiles:

    # split the filename and file extension for use in renaming the output file
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
    generated_output_file = file_name + "_regex" + file_extension

    # Only process certain types of files.
    if re.search("txt|doc|odt|htm|html")

    # Declare input and output files, open them, and start working on each line.
        input_file = os.path.join(path, f)
        output_file = os.path.join(path, generated_output_file)

        with open(input_file, "r") as fi, open(output_file, "w") as fo:
            for line in fi:

    # I realize that the examples are not regex, but they are in my real data.
    # The important thing, is that each of these is a substitution.
                line = re.sub(r"dog","cat" , line)
                line = re.sub(r"123", "789" , line)
                # Etc.

    # Obviously this doesn't work, because it is only writing the last instance of line.
                fo.write(line)
                fo.close()
```

Comment: What's your question? What problem are you having with your code?

Comment: You want to make a program that allows the user to use advanced search criterias without having to create himself the regex?

Comment: You should check `if file_extension in ["txt", "html", ...]` instead of doing re.search. But processing doc or odt files via regex will never work as these are not plain text documents: Old doc files are a proprietary binary format, newer docx files and odt are actually a zip file containing multiple xml files (the document itself, separate header / footer, style information etc), and even if you were to unzip it and process the right file, you could have arbitrary formatting syntax inbetween and even inside of words.

Comment: @interjay 1. I don't know how to apply multiple substitution regex  to a file and write the results to a new file. 2. If the rest of my code is OK, then it will run the list of regex on all the files of chosen file type in my directory.

Comment: @I4mpi. Thank you for pointing that out. Actually, I am planning on only processing txt and html  files. I added the file type selection part to the code because earlier versions of my script were trying to run the regex  on .DS_Store. This made me think that I didn't want any stray .mp3 or .jpg files being processed.  I'll remove .doc and .odt from the search.  // Please explain why to use if file_extension instead of re.search.

Comment: @Gabber (Sorry for the truncated post earlier. I tried answering on an android tablet). Ideally the regex list would reside in a separate file. But at this stage, I just need basic functionality. Getting the script to actually process and write multiple files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Unfortunately you didn't specify how you know which regexes are supposed to be applied, so I put them into a list of tuples (first element is the regex, second is the replacement text).

```
import os, os.path, re

path = "/Users/mypath/testData"
myfiles = os.listdir(path)
# its much faster if you compile your regexes before you
# actually use them in a loop
REGEXES = [(re.compile(r'dog'), 'cat'),
           (re.compile(r'123'), '789')]
for f in myfiles:
    # split the filename and file extension for use in
    # renaming the output file
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
    generated_output_file = file_name + "_regex" + file_extension

    # As l4mpi said ... if odt is zipped, you'd need to unzip it first
    # re.search is slower than a simple if statement
    if file_extension in ('.txt', '.doc', '.odt', '.htm', '.html'):

        # Declare input and output files, open them,
        # and start working on each line.
        input_file = os.path.join(path, f)
        output_file = os.path.join(path, generated_output_file)

        with open(input_file, "r") as fi, open(output_file, "w") as fo:
            for line in fi:
                for search, replace in REGEXES:
                    line = search.sub(replace, line)
                fo.write(line)
        # both the input and output files are closed automatically
        # after the with statement closes
```

Comment: `file_extension` starts with `.` unless empty

Comment: thank you, haven't used it in a while, fixed it now

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I want to apply all regexes in the list. I have basically three different projects. 1. Basic punctuation cleanup. 2. spelling substitutions for standardization of Lao text 3. Processing shortcuts for html tagging.

When running your script, I do not get any errors, but nothing happens. No new *_regex.txt files are created.

Comment: Could be because of the bug pointed out by J.F. Sebastian ... try copy/pasting it again

Comment: Yes. The adding the . to the file_extension fixed the problem

Comment: For testing purposes I made three files t.txt, t2.txt, and t3.txt each with identical text:

    The numbers in order are 0123456789
    I like dogs.
    The first three letters of the alphabet are abc.
    I have had many dogs since I was a child.
    It is a "dog eat dog" world.
    The first three numbers are 123.
    abcdefg

Comment: I applied 3 regex as per Igor Serko's code above.

    [(re.compile(r'dog'), 'cat'),
    (re.compile(r'123'), '789'),
    (re.compile(r'abc'), 'xyz')]

Comment: with the results saved to t_regex.txt, t2_regex.txt and t3_regex.txt. The original files remained unchanged.:

    The numbers in order are 0789456789
    I like cats.
    The first three letters of the alphabet are xyz.
    I have had many cats since I was a child.
    It is a "cat eat cat" world.
    The first three numbers are 789.
    xyzdefg

So the code works as intended. Thank you.