# Python multiple regexes cleaning the file

Tags: python, regex, removing-whitespace

### Preface

It has been a while me not using python so I'm having issues with data cleaning. 
In notepad++ it goes really slow so I am looking for more efficient options in python.

### What I need

I need to clean over 100 files in one directory, all of them were extracted manually from SAP.

Steps that I am looking for:

1. Remove first line with `-----`
2. Remove third line with `-----`
3. Remove first and last character `|` from each line
4. Remove whitespaces where needed - between text I need to keep them

#### Original File

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MANDT|BUKRS|NETWR     |UMSKS|UMSKZ|AUGDT     |AUGBL|ZUONR              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  100  |1000 |23.321-   |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
|  100  |1000 |0.12      |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
|  100  |1500 |90        |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Expected Outcome

```
MANDT|BUKRS|NETWR|UMSKS|UMSKZ|AUGDT|AUGBL|ZUONR
100|1000|23.321-|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
100|1000|0.12|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
100|1500|90|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
```

---

The code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551338/multiple-regex-substitution-in-multiple-files-using-python) is what I'm trying to work with but I need help with regular expression composition. In Notepad++ I can use `\h+(\w+)\h+` and as a replace `\1` but here it doesn't work. Please help me to build a proper regex.

Comment: Ignore lines without `|`, Split on `|`, Trim, Join value with `|`.  No regex needed with this algo.

Comment: Thing is as I mentioned I haven't used python for a while - 1 year or so I think. Can you share some code pieces?

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches:

**--** using built-in `str` object functions:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()     # getting list of lines
    for l in lines:
        if not l.startswith('---'):   # skip dashed lines
            print('|'.join(map(str.strip, l.strip('|').split('|'))))
```

---

**--** using `re.sub()` function:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for l in lines:
        if not l.startswith('---'):
            print(re.sub(r'\|\s*|\s*\|', '|', l).strip('|'))
            # an auxiliary pattern for complex cases:
            # re.sub(r'\|\s*(\S*)\s*(?=\|)', '|\\1', l).strip('|')
```

---

The output:

```
MANDT|BUKRS|NETWR|UMSKS|UMSKZ|AUGDT|AUGBL|ZUONR
100|1000|23.321-|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
100|1000|0.12|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
100|1500|90|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
```

---

***Read/write*** mode:

To overwrite the current file with new content use the following approach:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r+') as f:   # 'r+' - read/write mode
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    f.seek(0)      # reset file pointer
    f.truncate()   # truncating file contents
    for l in lines:
        if not l.startswith('---'):
            # or f.write('|'.join(map(str.strip, l.strip('|').split('|'))) + '\n')
            f.write(re.sub(r'\|\s*|\s*\|', '|', l).strip('|') + '\n')
```

Comment: clever!  nice outside the box thinking vs just going down the regex route

Comment: How I can overwrite the file I am using? I don't want to print it. I was trying with l='|'.join(map(str.strip, l.strip('|').split('|'))) but it did not work.

Comment: @user2433705, see my last approach

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, there is one thing I still need to update - how to modify the regex to remove whitespaces that pop-up before numbers - I didn't include it in the original example. So in my case I have `|  100  |1000 |    
             23.321-   |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|`

Comment: @user2433705, see my update under comment `# an auxiliary pattern for complex cases:`

Comment: Can you please guide me how I should change the regex if instead of a pipe I have tab delimited files now? How I can change tabs to pipes?

Answer (score 0):

WRT the code snippet in reference, you can use following patterns:

```
REGEXES = [(re.compile(r'^[-\n]+',re.M), ''),
       (re.compile(r'([\s]+)?\|([\s]+)?'), '|')]
```

Comment: It gives a syntax error on 'gm part - what does it mean?

Comment: I wanted to use `^` to indicate the start of a line which needs a multi line flag to be set. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/YYgpoN/1). I have updated my answer with correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

Assuming all your files are in the same format, you could simply use a regex replace.

### Answer

You can view this in use on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/nwI0pI/1)

#### Explanation

This regex `[\t ]|-{2,}\s*|^\||\|$` will:

1. Catch all tab or space characters
2. Catch all `-` characters where two such characters follow each other (as well as any following whitespace characters)
3. Catch all lines beginning with the `|` character
4. Catch all lines ending with the `|` character

**Note that you must ensure global `g` and multi-line `m` modifiers are active.**

---

#### Code

Your final code should resemble the following:

```
import re

regex = r"[\t ]|-{2,}\s*|^\||\|$"

subst = ""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Where `test_str` contains the file's contents (such as below)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MANDT|BUKRS|NETWR     |UMSKS|UMSKZ|AUGDT     |AUGBL|ZUONR              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  100  |1000 |23.321-   |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
|  100  |1000 |0.12      |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
|  100  |1500 |90        |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Output

```
MANDT|BUKRS|NETWR|UMSKS|UMSKZ|AUGDT|AUGBL|ZUONR
100|1000|23.321-|||||TEXTIWANTTOKEEP
100|1000|0.12|||||TEXTIWANTTOKEEP
100|1500|90|||||TEXTIWANTTOKEEP
```

---

## Edit

### Answer

You can view this in use on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/nwI0pI/2)

#### Explanation

```
(?:^\|[\t ]*)|(?:[\t ]*\|$)|(?:(?<=\|)[\t ]*)|(?:[\t ]*(?=\|))|(?:-{2,}\s*)
```

The regex above will:

1. Catch `|` (only at the beginning of a line) followed by any number of tab or space characters
2. Catch any number of tab or space characters followed by `|` (only at the end of a line)
3. Catch any number of tab or space characters that follow `|`
4. Catch any number of tab or space characters that precede `|`
5. Catch all `-` characters where two such characters follow each other (as well as any following whitespace characters)

**Note that you must ensure global `g` and multi-line `m` modifiers are active.**

---

#### Code

Your final code should resemble the following:

```
import re

regex = r"(?:^\|[\t ]*)|(?:[\t ]*\|$)|(?:(?<=\|)[\t ]*)|(?:[\t ]*(?=\|))|(?:-{2,}\s*)"

subst = ""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Where `test_str` contains the file's contents (such as below)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MANDT|BUKRS|NETWR     |UMSKS|UMSKZ|AUGDT     |AUGBL|ZUONR              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  100  |1000 |23.321-   |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
|  100  |1000 |0.12      |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
|  100  |1500 |90        |     |     |          |     |TEXT I WANT TO KEEP|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Output

```
MANDT|BUKRS|NETWR|UMSKS|UMSKZ|AUGDT|AUGBL|ZUONR
100|1000|23.321-|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
100|1000|0.12|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
100|1500|90|||||TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
```

Comment: Many thanks but how to adjust it so it not removes spaces between text? I have some text attributes there as well where I need to keep spaces.